# Save file in Music folder windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I've a code which download music from streaming link, how can I save it in the Music folder of windowsphone? I've read many topic about isolated storage but if save in isolated storage, user can't copy file when connect phone to computer.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only work on Windows Phone 8 but you can use the [MediaLibraryExtensions.SaveSong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.xna.framework.media.PhoneExtensions.medialibraryextensions.savesong%28v=xnagamestudio.42%29.aspx) method. Download the song to isolated storage and move it from there to the `MediaLibrary`.

Comment: Yes, SaveSong isn't supported on 7.1. There's no way to save a song to the MediaLibrary on 7.1 at all.